# Store and search IPv6 ranges in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ipv6

I have a CVS database which gives a V6 range `2001:1800::/32` and a country code `US`. So far I have them in `$ip_address` `$cc_code`.

I need to store each range in MySQL. I also need take a user IP address and get the country code. I already got V4 working by storing a start and end range but the database already gave me that. So I'm stuck on getting V6 to work. I did some Google searches and can't find much on this. Maybe I'm asking wrong? So can someone here give me some advice? I already know how to detect V4 and V6. So I have lots of it done so far. Just storing range/code and retiring it where i'm stuck.

Comment: Did you get everything working? Any chance you could post your solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IP addressed are basically Integers, you just need to convert them and the interact with basic math skills: WHERE $ip BETWEEN `start` AND `end`. http://www.samclarke.com/2011/07/php-ipv6-to-128bit-int/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6.3 introduced the following new functions to work with IPv6 addresses:

> [INET6_ATON()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton) Return the numeric value of an IP address
>
> [INET6_NTOA()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-ntoa) Return the IP address from a numeric value

For example, `hex(INET6_ATON('fdfe::5a55:caff:fefa:9089'))` returns `FDFE0000000000005A55CAFFFEFA9089`

You can store IPv6 in your database as `VARBINARY(16)`